# How to change DayNight theme manually?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented successfully NightMode in my app, but just when it is > API29 (Android Q).
In older APIs, I don't have the feature of automatic DayNight theme (According to the OS), so I use a switch to manually trigger the theme, and then, it saves the theme in Preferences so it'll load the theme when the user starts the Activity again. This is the switch code (this code is inside a fragment):

```
DarkSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
            if (b) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                p.setBoolean("NightMode", true); //P is an instance of a class I have called PrefUtils that saves the user preferences
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                p.setBoolean("NightMode", false);
            }
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).recreate();
        });
```

The code above works fine, it restarts the Activity with the desired theme and saves the boolean in the preferences. However, the main problem is when I restart the app. The Activity changes theme before `setContentView()`, and loads the theme, but after trying to access to my Database from an AsyncTask, it throws an exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory,
>   android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

My guess is that somehow, changing the theme can cause the Context to be null, and this null context is passed to the fragments, same ones that try to access the database through an AsyncTask, and it throws the exception.
It is weird, because the app only crashes when loading the Activity (it does not crash in the first code snippet), and only crashes if the `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` gets executed, thing that will only happen if the user has the Preference "NightMode" set to true.

This is my Activity code:

```
private void initTheme() {
        PrefUtils p = new PrefUtils(this);
        if (p.getBoolean("NightMode", false) || AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            getDelegate().applyDayNight();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initTheme();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initFragments();
}
```

**EDIT**
I access the Database values through my FolderFragment, same one that is attached to the activity in initFragments():

```
public Fragment fragment1 = new FolderFragment();
private void initFragments()
{
     fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fragment1, "1").commit();
}
```

This is my FolderFragment's code:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.folderfragment, container, false);
        new RefreshData(v).execute();


        return v;
    }

 private class RefreshData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private View v;
        private String title;
        private Drawable drawable;

        public RefreshData(View v) {
            this.v = v;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Progress = v.findViewById(R.id.FFProgress); //Progress is my ProgressBar
            Progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            PAdapter = new ListAdapter(mList, getContext(), Mode);
            Pager.setAdapter(PAdapter);
            Progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Hides the ProgressBar because has finished 
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            mList = getLists();
            return null;
        }

private void getLists()
{
        ArrayList<ListItem> l = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseHelper d = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

        Cursor res = d.getAllLists();

        try
        {
            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                int ID = res.getInt(0);
                int FolderID = res.getInt(1);
                String Title = res.getString(2);
                String Description = res.getString(3);
                String ColorHex = res.getString(4);
                int Tag = res.getInt(5);

                l.add(new ListItem(ID, FolderID, Title, Description, ColorHex, Tag));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ignored)
        {

        }
        return l;
    }

    }
```

This class `"DatabaseHelper"` is the one that manages all the select and insert statements:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public Cursor getAllLists() {
        try
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //This is where throws the exception
            return db.rawQuery(Db.Query.SELECT_LISTS, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the code for you accessing the database is it in initFragments? show us that

Comment: @Blundell just updated the question with the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is not attached to the Activity/Fragment inside `onCreateView` (that's what the `false` in the inflation is also saying. `false` means don't attach because when you return your view from that method the system will attach it).

Which is dangerous in itself to start manipulating the view, and executing tasks that use the view & context at that point.

I would move `new RefreshData(v).execute();` into `onActivityCreated`.

---

However your problem is your ASyncTask is non-static, that's why you can use the `getContext()` method inside of it. So the problem is either the task is holding an old reference and it's becoming null, or its asking for a reference too early in the lifecycle and its null.

I think the above mentioned fix to move to `onActivityCreated` may fix it, but it's still not the best.

I would then change your ASyncTask to make it static:

`private static class RefreshData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {`

Then change anywhere you use `getContext()` to `v.getContext()` i.e.

`new DatabaseHelper(getContext());`

becomes

`new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext());`

You could also pass the context explicitly, like the way you pass the view. That'd be even better. Actually best would be to do this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    ProgressBar progressView = findViewById(R.id.FFProgress);
    new RefreshData(dbHelper, progressView).execute();
}

 private static class RefreshData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final View progress;
        private final DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        private String title;
        private Drawable drawable;

        public RefreshData(DatabaseHelper dbHelper, View progress) {
            this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
            this.progress = progress;
        }
```

Etc.. so that you epxlicitly declare what the task uses, and pass them in from the activity.

---

Side note:

you have a lot of variables starting with an uppercase character, like:

```
String Title = res.getString(2);
```

You should avoid doing this to not confuse yourself. The idomatic agreement of java developers is to name Classes with an uppercase characte, such as `DatabaseHelper` and variables with a lowercase such as `title`. Then to camelcase any further words. So this becomes:

`String title = res.getString(2);`